# create view case based in sql

Tags: sql, view

I have a table of 3 columns A,B,C

initially column C is completely empty and for every entry either A has a number or B has a number (never both in the same row)

I want to create a view that checks for every row if A=x and B is null or 0 then write the value of A in col.

EXAMPLE:
[image]

Can someone help guide me, I am still new to sql

Comment: and what should be "written" when it isn't?

Comment: you can't do it while creating a view until and unless we get values fior A and B. give us view sql query for  A and B.

Comment: I added a picture of an example if it helps @nbk

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: so it has to be done it 2 separate queries? @nikhil sungandh

Comment: I am sorry for adding a picture but I tried making the table example on here but it was not showing right. I am also new here. Idk ehatto do. I follow the stackover flow format but its not working so can you just accept the picture for now @nbk

Answer (score 0):

You can'z use a VIEW for that but an `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE mytable 
    SET C = CASE WHEN A > 0 AND (B IS NULL OR B = 0) THEN A 
            ELSE B END
```

Thsi will not include what happens wehen A > 0 and B > 0 as you haven't specify what to do so this query will always take A before B

Comment: A and B will never both >0 in the same row in my table

Comment: Good so the query will work as you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume a table ABC with column A, B and C as you mentioned

```
create table abc (a     int ,b      int ,c      int )
```

**And you want to display column C as value of either A or B based upon value**
then you can create View by two methods to achieve the desired result

1. Using CASE

> ```
> create view abc_v1
> as 
> select a, b, case when isnull(a,0)=0 then b else a end "c"
> from
> abc
> ```

2. using Coalesce: considering the values would be either 0 or some value, we can mark column A/B as NULL when value is zero and use Coalesce

> ```
> create view abc_v2
> as
> select a,b, coalesce(nullif(a,0),nullif(b,0)) as "c"
> from abc
> ```

Or else,
If you want to update Column C with Value of col A/B then

> Update ABC
> set c = coalesce(nullif(a,0),nullif(b,0))

Answer (score 0):

Try this view. It spells out your requirement.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW abc_with_c AS
SELECT a, b,
       CASE WHEN a = 0 OR a IS NULL THEN b
            WHEN b = 0 OR b IS NULL THEN a
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS c
  FROM abc;
```

It's a good idea in SQL to write statements so they're easy to read and reason about.